# Map inside Windows Store App

Tags: c#, google-maps, maps, bing-maps, windows-store-apps

I'd like to embed a map into a Windows Store App. I'd like smooth zooming / panning and to pin interactive elements to geographical locations.

I assume my alternatives are either Bing Maps or Google Maps? Should I go with embedding a browser control and if so, is it difficult to control/interact with programmatically?

Any other alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408457/Using-Bing-Maps-For-Windows-8-Metro-Apps-Csharp-Ja

In haven't tried it myself , but I am about to and will post findings.

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll check it out.

Comment: Just tries a quick prototype should meet your requirements.